# how to get some margin in the axis of a chart qml

Tags: qt, charts, qml

I have made a chart in qml, everything is fine. The only thing I can't do is to have some spacing between the axis x and the value of its axis. I mean how can I put some margin? Because now I have the label of the x nearly attached to the x axis. Is there some anchors.margin or spacing to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @augre I just have a DateTimeAxis where I display on the x axis the datetime.
I just want to give some margin between the x axis and the datetime value. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved putting a `<br>` in the format property of the date.

```
format: "<br>dd-MM-yyyy"
```

At least I have a space between the label and the axis.

Comment: Thanks! I've added space in my case: `labelFormat: "%.0f "`.